# How can I make the animation happen every time I click?

Tags: javascript, css

I want the card shake everytime I click, but its only happens the first time I click. I want that to happen on every click I make.

JavaScript:

```
var card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", function(){
    card.classList.add("shake");
});
```

CSS:

```
.shake{
    animation: move 1.3s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you click again, the card already has the `shake` class, so nothing new happens. Remove the class after the animation period, via the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event:

```
var card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", function(){
    card.classList.add("shake");
});
card.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    card.classList.remove("shake");
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", function(){
    card.classList.add("shake");
});
card.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
    card.classList.remove("shake");
});
```

```css
.shake{
    animation: move 1.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes move {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">This is the card</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer is to remove the `shake` class and add it back in a `setTimeout()` of `0ms`. This gives the browser a change to know that the class was removed before adding it back.

Javascript:

```
var card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", function(){
    card.classList.remove("shake");
    setTimeout(function(){card.classList.add("shake");},0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are never actually removing the `.shake` class you added on card which is responsible for the animation of your card for the first time.
Try this it will remove `.shake` class after 3 secs and you will be able to shake your card on the click again. You should change the time delay of 3000 according to your need.

```
var card = document.querySelector(".card");
card.addEventListener("click", function(){
    card.classList.add("shake");
    setTimeout(function(){ card.classList.remove("shake") }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to duplicate the times like that (once in the CSS, again in the JavaScript). Instead, (as I said in my answer), use the `animationend` event.

Comment: Agreed. `animationend` is the correct approach and the right way. Thanks for sharing wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unless you later decide to remove the animation and just change background-color or god forbid are still using IE. then a `setTimeout` is needed because `animationend` is never triggered

Comment: @dehart - Not using an animation would completely change the question (and remove the duplication I mentioned above), and thus change the answer. IE11 supports `animationend` (I just tried it). (IE9 doesn't support animation. I don't have IE10 handy and MDN's documentation doesn't say when IE got support for `animationend`, but suffice to say IE10 is completely irrelevant today.)

Comment: Thanks, I looked at MDN as well, it had a question mark. caniuse said it is supported since IE11. One could argue that changing the style in a single frame is still an animation. I've added an answer as an alternative (How I do it myself often).

Comment: (I should have said: IE9 doesn't support the animation syntax the OP is using...)

Comment: (Just for completeness on the above: IE10+ have `animationend`, I updated the MDN compat data.)